# PYTHON- REMOVE empty lines of variable containing several values

Tags: python, arrays

Good evening community,

I'm currently writing a python script which outputs me a variable that contains several values. The name of the variable is 'y'( to be more precisely: I defined y as an array y= []) it gets filled with position data in form of x,y,z coordinates by a function. When i print the variable y the data looks like the following:

```
[[[ 22.67971815  -8.74924581  74.37963044]]  

[[[  0.80132995  -9.97601029  73.91042767]]]  

[[[-20.7922284  -12.16091024  71.74796926]]]
```

My question:

Is there a way to remove the empy rows between the data rows? In addtion, is it possible to remove the brackets `([[[...]]])` of the variable y ?

Glad for any any help and thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a code example, please?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the brackets you can use list [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). In your case, I would do something like the following.

```
stripped_y = [item.strip("[]") for item in y]
```

Comment: Thanks foryour reply. Applying your suggestion i receive the following Error msg: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'strip' Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: He assumed your y is a string, but as we can see it is a numpy array. Therefore, it would be really good to know how you created y in order to help you.

Comment: A openCV function returns me the value of y :                                                                                                         x,y = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(bla, 20.1, camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients, None, None and stores the data within the variable. Later on i print the variable y into a table                                                             
        t = Texttable()
        t.add_rows([["ID","tvecs"], [str(markerIDs),str(y)]])     
        print(str(t.draw()))

Comment: Note: marker ID is as well a variable, which values are defined by a function and are included in the table.